# How to loop through dictionary list and extract one key with boolean value

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm working on twitter data collected using Streaming API and was trying to remove all retweeted tweets. 
A single item in my dataset looks like this:

```
tweets_data[5]

{'contributors': None,
 'coordinates': None,
 'created_at': 'Thu Mar 09 15:14:10 +0000 2017',
... ...
 'retweet_count': 0,
 'retweeted': False,
... ...}
```

And I wrote a loop to do the job:

```
tweets_Rt_Removed = []
for tweet in tweets_data:
    if tweet['retweeted'] == True:
        tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)

print(len(tweets_Rt_Removed))
```

But it gave me an error like this:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-d44896eca6fd> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for tweet in tweets_data:
----> 6     if tweet['retweeted'] == True:
      7         tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
      8 

KeyError: 'retweeted'
```

I also use "try except" to avoid any error caused by incomplete tweets, but it return the length 0.

Is this an error caused by boolean value?
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is retweeted always present?

Comment: You also don't need to do the == True. You can simply do if tweet['retweeted']: which evaluated as true

Comment: Are you trying to remove all retweeted tweets or collect them, cause in this way you are just collecting them...

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem solved. And yes, I should have use " if not tweet['retweeted]" to remove retweets. And definitely "try, except" as not all dictionary contain key: 'retweeted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap

```
if tweet['retweeted'] == True:
        tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
```

with:

```
try:
    if tweet['retweeted']:  # Will throw a key error if it doesn't have a retweet
        tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
except KeyError:
    pass  # No retweeted == good
```

Comment: Thanks! this works. "except KeyError: Pass" Helped. I wrote "except: continue", which didn't return anything.

Comment: @Daisywang `continue` at the end of the loop should be effectively a `pass`... but I'm glad it worked for you.

Comment: It seems lame to me to try: except: pass something that you could actually check is valid :)

Comment: @Artagel As [repl.it](https://repl.it/Fm5X/3) demonstrates, if the miss rate is less than around 30%, try/except is faster than checking

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to troubleshoot this is to do this:

```
tweets_Rt_Removed = []
for tweet in tweets_data:
    try:
        if tweet['retweeted']:  # no == True necessary
            tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
    except:
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

When you get the traceback, it'll go to pdb, then you can type: tweet

That will show you the contents of the specific tweet, and you can see if your key is there or not.

If it isn't there, then you just need to check first if it exists:

```
if 'retweeted' in tweet:
    do your stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the dictionary function `get` which has built-in error checking and allows you provide a default value in case the key doesn't exist for some values.

```
tweets_Rt_Removed = []
for tweet in tweets_data:
    if tweet.get('retweeted', default=False):
        tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)

print(len(tweets_Rt_Removed))
```

If you are trying to make a list of tweets that have not been retweeted, you'd actually want to to append all tweets where "retweeted" is False:

```
tweets_Rt_Removed = []
for tweet in tweets_data:
    if not tweet.get('retweeted', default=False):
        tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)

print(len(tweets_Rt_Removed))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Consumers of Tweets should tolerate the addition of new fields and
>   variance in ordering of fields with ease. Not all fields appear in all
>   contexts. It is generally safe to consider a nulled field, an empty
>   set, and the absence of a field as the same thing.[Reference](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets)

So you can change

```
if tweet['retweeted'] == True:
    tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
```

to

```
if tweet.get('retweeted', False) is True:
    tweets_Rt_removed.append(tweet)
```

In this case, if there are some tweets without retweeted field, you will skip them.

Comment: According to PEP 285 True, False and None are singletons.
If you want to make sure that a variable is a boolean and of value True, use the is operator.
The condition in if x: will be considered as True if x is "False" (or any non-empty string, any non-empty list, or tuple.
So using is operator is the pythonic and correct way.
"Explicit is better than implicit "

Comment: @FarhadMaleki Ultimately it's a stylistic choice, but I agree with juanpa - especially for a boolean value (as OP shows), `if value:` is the generally accepted method.

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It is a programming style. 
I recommend is operator since I have seen many bugs resulted from using if x: style. It is more readable and explicit too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect all tweets which have not been retweeted in a single list:

```
not_retweeted = [t for t in tweets_data if not t.get('retweeted', False)]
```

Or only those which have been retweeted:

```
retweeted = [t for t in tweets_data if t.get('retweeted', False)]
```

This assumes that `tweets_data` is a list containing dictionaries as items.

Also, tweets (dictionaries) missing the key `'retweeted'` will be counted as tweets which have not been retweeted. Hence, only tweets which explicitly contain `'retweeted': True` will be considered retweeted.